# is this a java compiler bug?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Compiler gives a compilation error that does not make sense.
"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field x"
I do not make a static reference. A static inner class should have access to the private members of the enclosing class. In fact it does allow me to access super.x

I tried this with java 1.8

```
class Bug
{
   private int x = 0;
   int y;

   static class BugDerived extends Bug
   {
      BugDerived()
      {
         super();

         super.y = 1; // no error
         y = 1;       // no error
         super.x = 1; // no error !
         x = 1;  // ERROR
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: no, no bug, it seems to be design! :) `x` is not `static` , but `BugDerived` is...

Comment: `A static inner class should have access to the private members of the parent class.` <- What makes you think that? A static inner class is pretty much the same as defining the inner class in its own file.

Comment: @SPIDERS  Yes, sorry, I meant an inner class, static or not,should have access to the private members of the *enclosing* class. So in this case BugDerived should be allowed to access Bug.x because it is defined as an inner class of Bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a static method can only reference static fields or other methods. By calling super().x you reference a non-static property from a non-static context, which is allowed.

The following quote is taken from Oracle [website](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

> Non-static nested classes (inner classes) have access to other members of the enclosing class, even if they are declared private. Static nested classes do not have access to other members of the enclosing class.

The inner static class do **not** have access to members (private methods/variables) of the enclosing class.

Also look [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nested-classes-java/):

> a static nested class cannot refer directly to instance variables or
>   methods defined in its enclosing class: it can use them only through
>   an object reference. They are accessed using the enclosing class name.

Comment: Yes, but without the super prefix I *also* reference ...., which is allowed. Also view edited code.

Comment: Yes, that does explain all 4 cases.  In this code it was not so obvious because the static nested class is also derived from the enclosing class. A nice question for a quiz.

Answer (score 0):

A static inner class is linked to the outer class at class level, not instance level.

As a result, it can only access static members of the outer class, working in that respect identical to static methods.

Hence, this is not a compiler bug, it's expected behaviour.

When you use super.x, you're accessing the x data member from the instance of the superclass that underlies the instance of the nested class for which the constructor is being run, thus it does have access.

Comment: I agree about what you say about super.x, but I do not see why leaving out super would make a difference. Also see my modified code, and note that for field y I do not get any compiler error.